# $.getJSON is not getting the values to show as a line graph

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, highcharts

[image]I have two files

```
searh_journal.php

<script type="text/javascript">
function submitForm() {

    var form = document.myform;

    var dataString = $(form).serialize();

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'journal_table/get_data_journ.php',
        data: dataString,
        success: function (data) {
            $('#container_journal').html(data);

            var options = {
                chart: {
                    renderTo: 'container_journal',
                    plotBackgroundColor: null,
                    plotBorderWidth: null,
                    plotShadow: false
                },

                xAxis: {
                    title: {
                        text: 'Year'
                    },
                    categories: []
                },

                yAxis: {
                    title: {
                        text: 'Number of Citations'
                    },
                    plotLines: [{
                        value: 0,
                        width: 1,
                        color: '#808080'
                    }]
                },

                series: [{
                    type: 'line',
                    color: '#0066FF',
                    name: 'Citations',
                    data: []
                }]
            }

            $.getJSON("journal_table/get_data_journ.php", function (data) {
                $.each(data, function (key, value) {
                    $.each(value, function (key, value) {
                        options.series[0].data = value;
                    });
                });

                chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
            });


        }
    });
    return false;
}
</script>


<div id="container_journal"></div>
```

get_data_journ.php

```
<? php
include '../connect.php';


$hello = $_POST['checkedname'];
foreach($hello as $key = > $values) {
    $result_journ = mysql_query("SELECT year, citations, jour_id FROM journ_graph WHERE jour_id = '$values'");

    $rows_journ = array();
    while ($r_journ = mysql_fetch_array($result_journ)) {
        $row_journ[0] = $r_journ[0];
        $row_journ[1] = $r_journ[1];
        array_push($rows_journ, $row_journ);
    }


    print json_encode($rows_journ, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);

}
```

The output is like this

```
            | Journal Name | Edgefactor |
    Checkbox| journal1     | 0.56       |
    Checkbox| journal2     | 0.34       |
    Checkbox| journal3     | 0.32       |
    Checkbox| journal4     | 0.14       |
    Checkbox| journal5     | 0.54       |

                       Compare Journal button
```

Here if the user chooses two journals and he wants to compare two journals(Refer Picture), he can click on the compare journal button, then the graph must be shown for that two journals.

Here the `html` part is working i mean the plain `html` `json` data is shown, but the graph is not showing, the problem is in the `$.getJson()` line I guess.

Comment: Your `$.each()` loop is writing each element of the JSON array into just one element of `options`, so you don't get the whole series.

Comment: Bro please help me I don't know how to do that?

Answer (score 3):

You need to add the appropriate elements of each row of the JSON array to the `categories` and `data` arrays in the options.

```
$.getJSON("journal_table/get_data_journ.php", function (data) {
    $.each(data, function (key, value) {
        options.xAxis.categories.push(value[0]);
        options.series.data.push(value[1]);
    });
```

Comment: Actually the graph is not showing bro. problem in get_data_journ.php file. because of the foreach statement. If I remove the foreach statement query without the where clause then the line graph is shown for all the journal.

Comment: You can't return multiple JSON arrays like that, a JSON script has to return just a single result. You need to add another dimension to the result array, for each graph you want to print, and then call `print json_encode()` outside of the loop. Then your JS needs to add an element to options.series for each of these, giving them different colors (maybe HighCharts will automatically do that if you leave out the `color:` option). This is a big rewrite of your code, I'm not interested in doing that right now.

Comment: Bro please help me out with this, almost I have done just to show the graph. Please help bro.

Comment: What's with this "bro" stuff? I see it all the time on SO. Anyway, I think I've explained what you need to do pretty clearly. If you can't figure out how to turn that into code, you're in the wrong line of work. Sorry to be harsh.